# jQuery apply transition on element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

I'm trying to apply my *fade* transition every time I click the button.

**What is the best practice to achieve this?**

> So instead of .addClass() and then .removeClass() after it is added,
>   imagine something like .apply() that would just apply the class once
>   so it doesn't "keep" the class.

Right now I have `.toggleClass` which only applies the transition every other click (basically like: addClass, removeClass, addClass, and so on). I can think of doing it another way by looking to see if it already has the class, and if not, then remove it and add it again, but it seems so counter-intuitive and makes me think there must be a simpler and cleaner way to do this.

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $("#cat").toggleClass("fade");
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yatra+One');

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.generator {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#cat {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade {
  animation: fade .5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#btn {
  height: 90px;
  width: 400px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #4682B4;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  font-family: Yatra One;
  transition: background-color 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

#btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #508EC3;
}

#btn:active {
  background-color: #4293D8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="generator">
    <img id="cat" src="https://i.imgur.com/RVQZ9UM.png" alt="cat" />
    <button id="btn">New cat</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the `fade` class at the end of animation by listening to the animation events:

```
$("#cat").bind('oanimationend animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function() { 
   $(this).removeClass("fade");
});
```

In this case you  may use `addClass` instead of `toggleClass`.

Comment: Even though it works nicely, it is still just another way of adding and then removing the class. It is what I want, but I was looking for a way to do this with 1 function. So instead of `.addClass()` and then `.removeClass()` after it is added, imagine something like `.apply()` that would just apply the class once so it doesn't "keep" the class.

Comment: If you don't like to stuck in CSS classes, you can use jquery.transit plugin to apply all kinds of css animations using jquery just on click. http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ @SirExotic

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a way to apply both add- and removeClass in one function, thanks for your help anyway :) I'll take a look at the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `toogleClass()` here might not be the best solution. What happens is :

1. At startup the `<img>` doesn't have the `.fade` class
2. When you click the button, the class is added, hence launching the keyframe animation
3. But when you click again, it removes the class
4. So you have to click one more time to relaunch the animation

But for now I don't have a better way of doing that. And Nandita's answer has actually the same behavior with a bit more code.

Ali's one is actually the best one :

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
      $("#cat").addClass("fade");
})

$("#cat").bind('oanimationend animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function() { 
   $(this).removeClass("fade");
});
```

Listening to the animation event to remove the `.fade` class when the animation is done.